# Encrypt Files in Android native code

Tags: android, c++, encryption, compression, zlib

I need to encrypt the zip file (generated from 5-6 files of size 50 MB) which are created by the android native service written in C++.

After doing google learned that there are some open source libs which can help to do the encryption. But I would like to know if there is any inbuilt support to achieve the encryption.

Code flow : Read log files create a custom logs and write to the desired location, zip and encrypt the files

Note : even if i can compress the file with password protection is enough for me.

Comment: Do you want to encrypt the zip file itself or the contents of the zip file using zip encryption?

Comment: I want to encrypt zip file itself

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no standard Java mechanism to password protect a zip file.  You will have to use a third party library.

Comment: Thanks Doug, Can you please suggest which open source encryption lib will be good ? Crypto ++  ?

Comment: I have never done this myself, but I did a google search and found this.  http://java.sys-con.com/node/1258827